# Google Cloud Pricing insane? How to set up correctly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to understand how the google pricing works for SQL. I am quite surprised by the charges I got and working out if I have done something wrong.

I just set up an instance, did some migrations, seeding etc and noticed the pricing I got and data in the chart. I attached some images.

Also, the chart shows 1.245G of usage, is this for keeping a connection?

So far its 7e for just that? I am one person who is using it at the moment. This is only for 2 days or so.

Is this right? What if I get 100 or 1000 users using it regularly? is that going to be 7000e per day?

Best regards

[image: Data chart]

[image]

**UPDATE**
Thanks for the replies below. Yes, I did have a look at the pricing, I have a screen grab below of what the pricing should be as they state, and what I have set up. However the charge of 7e makes no sense as at that rate I am going to be charged 140e not 50e. I only spun up an instance and did a migration, with no data. There is hardly any Egress (I am the only one using it as testing). I also should be on micro not standard so that should reduce the price somewhat.

Also please look at the graph, (SQL storage used) how could be at 1.222G (or over) when all I have done is create an instance and put 3 tables in there and no data. Does this graph represent keeping the instance always on? Does this mean traffic? Its always climbing, despite inactivity. What storage could I possible have used? (That storage dip is when I created a new instance, but once again it rises without any activity)

[image]

Comment: Here is Google's page on Cloud SQL pricing ... https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing  as you will see, the costs are broken out and explained.    Among the factors involved are type of SQL (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server), number of vCPUs, amount of memory, HA considerations, storage, Internet Egress.  Just looking at storage costs isn't enough.  According to the website, its about 21 cents per GB per month.

Comment: Google Cloud SQL Server is charged by the hour or month. I do not see a problem with the pricing that you are showing. Read the pricing page and do your own calculations. Also, you have provided no details on how you have configured the service.

Comment: thanks Kolban and John, I have posted an update to explain things a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the Cloud SQL pricing page, you'll see the following:

> Instance pricing for Second Generation is charged for *every minute
>   that the instance is running* (the activation policy is set to ALWAYS).
>   The charge depends on the machine type you choose for the instance,
>   and the region where the instance is located.

It doesn't look like you actually have a micro (shared core) instance being used (that looks like a small, standard size instance).

Regarding the storage usage - This is the total amount of disk that your instance has used, including logs and database installation. It's going to flex some as logs increase in size and are rotated (this is normal). The graph in question may look drastic, but it is showing a change of only a few MBs.

Comment: Thank you! That chart is misleading, but now I understand it includes more that just what data you have on your database. As you say its only a few MB, but I saw 1.2G, while having an empty DB and was like whaa, with 7e on the bill. As mentioned, I was surprised that pricing didn't correlate to what the pricing stated and what I was charged (ie 7e for 1.5 days, which should be about the 1.50e mark per day at standard).  I am now on micro, and will carry on with that.